# Invalid property ScrollTrigger Gsap Laravel

Tags: laravel, installation, gsap

I'm facing a warning in laravel after installing Gsap: "Invalid property ScrollTrigger set to {trigger: "js-title-animation2", start: "20px 80%", markers: true, toggleActions: "resart pause reverse none"} Missing plugin? gsap.registerPlugin()"

file.blade.php

```
@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/newHome.js') }}"></script>
<script src=" {{asset('/js/scripts/gsap.min.js') }} "></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/scripts/ScrollTrigger.min.js')}}"></script>

<script>
//    TweenMax.to('.js-title-animation', 1, {rotation: 360});
// gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
gsap.to('.js-title-animation', {duration: 3, text: '@lang('home.header-title-new-home')', ease: "none"});
// gsap.to('.js-title-animation2', {duration: 3, text: '@lang('home.header-subtitle-new-home')', ease: "none"});
gsap.to('.js-title-animation2', {ScrollTrigger: {
    trigger: 'js-title-animation2',
    start: "20px 80%",
    markers: true,
    toggleActions: "resart pause reverse none"
},
x: 200,
rotation: 360,
duration: 3
});

</script>
@endection
```

Comment: Also tried to uncomment "// gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);" ,.... but nothing!!

Comment: You need to include your custom JS *after* you load GSAP and ScrollTrigger. Make sure that the file path to your ScrollTrigger file is correct (or load it from a CDN). And make sure to register ScrollTrigger. For more info, see [the GSAP installation page](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation).

Comment: Also, you're using the wrong case in your tween:
BAD: {ScrollTrigger:...}
GOOD: {scrollTrigger:...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably have incompatible versions of gsap and ScrollTrigger

// this works for me

< script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.0/gsap.js">

< script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.0/ScrollTrigger.js">

// source
https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation?checked=core,scrollTrigger,debug#CDN

sorry for my poor english